# Click function in Jquery on different .aspx pages

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have two pages: `index.aspx` and `dream.aspx`. I have a button `click me` on `index.aspx` Here's my Jquery code that clicks on that button:

```
function createItemButton()
    {
        setTimeout(
        function()
        {
            $("#CreateItem").click();
        },5000);    //Delay of 5 seconds


    }
createItemButton();
```

The delay added is because of the rest of the code not posted here. Once the `click me` button is triggered, it takes me to the dream.aspx page. There's another button `back` on that page, which when clicked, takes me back to the `index.aspx` page. Here's my attempt to automate everything:

```
function createItemButton()
{
    setTimeout(
    function()
    {
      $("#CreateItem").click(); //id of click me button on index.aspx page
    },5000);    //Delay of 5 seconds


 }

function createItemButton1()
{
    setTimeout(
    function()
    {
      $("#back").click();  //id of back button on dream.aspx page
    },7000);    //Delay of 7 seconds


 }
 function call()
 {
    createItemButton();
    createItemButton1();
 }
 call();
```

My thinking is that once it redirects to the `dream.aspx` page, it'll wait another 2 seconds ( 7000 - 5000 delay ) and the trigger a click on the back button and take me back to the `index.aspx` page. But for some reason, after it is taking me to the `dream.aspx` page, it's not triggering a click on the back button on the same page. I have tried giving multiple delays in the same `setTimeout()` function also. Something like:

```
function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#CreateItem").click();
        $("#back").click();
    }, 3000));
}
```

I have been informed that this code will give a delay of 3 seconds to each of the clicks. But it did not work for me. I also tried a couple of other things but nothing worked.

Basically, once I move from the `index.aspx` page after clicking on the `click me` button, I want the `back` button on the `dream.aspx` page to take me back to the `index.aspx` page after a couple of seconds. All automated. FYI, I am running this code in console. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can maybe create or click the button on the new page once the new page is loaded...if it suits. But the current code will not work because once the new page is loaded, previous JS code is removed.

Comment: @PEJK: Thank you for replying. I know it's lost. That's why I am here. Is there a way to preserve it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

The code for `back` button (`function createItemButton1()`) and its call must be placed in `dream.aspx`. Once you leave `index.aspx`, all javascript code in it is gone along with any pending timeouts.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Will try that. Is there a way to preserve the JavaScript? Just want to know if I can achieve the same without altering the code at all. Can I not do that using just the console? I wanna keep 'making changes to my main code' as my last option.

Comment: I don't understand what "just using console" means. Is your code not in the page, but typed into the browser console, while you are debugging?